# AngularJS controller not displaying data in view

Tags: angularjs

I have the following controller which I use to display data in my index.html footer area but unfortunately nothing is displayed. I've double checked code but can't seem to find anything, so I was wondering if someone can please help by telling me what I am doing wrong here and how to fix it? Thanks

Note: One thing I noticed though while reproducing the error. If I just navigated to the app url say domainname.com/#/ nothing is displayed from the FooterCntrl, but I navigated to any internal page FooterCntrl data is displayed, and if I returned back to home page FooterCntrl data is displayed. Yet once I refresh the home page, FooterCntrl data is gone again....

Index.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>....</head>
....
<div ng-view></div>
....
<div id="footerzone" ng-controller="FooterCntrl">
  <div class="col">
    <h6>Data from controller - {{footerData}}</h6>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

FooterCntrl.js

```
myApp.controller('FooterCntrl',
    function FooterCntrl($scope){
        $scope.footerData = "Footer Data";
});
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']);
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
       $routeProvider.when('/', 
                {     templateUrl: 'templates/index.html', 
                      controller: 'HController',
                      title: 'Welcome Home Page'
                });

..... etc of routes
```

Comment: From what you have provided it all looks ok. Are you able to provide more code (fiddle?). Also are you getting any console errors?

Comment: @MattWay I've just updated my question with more testing results. Thanks

Comment: Are you overwriting myApp when you declare your controllers? Or are your controllers in the same file as your router? If they are in a separate file, make a separate module for your controllers, and inject it into your myApp along with 'ngRoute' and 'ngSanitize'

Comment: @ZackArgyle All the app controllers are in separate file each, so for example FooterCntrl is in FooterCntrl.js and all of them are included in the index.html before the closing </body>. Can you please provide an example of what do you mean by separate module for the controllers?

Comment: I think he is refering to use a new module `var myApp = angular.module('footerModule', []);` and then declaring your controller using `footerModule` instead of `myApp`.

Comment: @FedericoNafria Just to make sure I got this clear, so I will have like 2 apps each with its own module? Example: var myApp1= angular.module('footerModule', []); and var myapp2 = angular.module('myApp', []); ?

Comment: Yes, those are not really apps, those are modules. And, the `myApp` module should include the `footerModule`.
`var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'footerModule']);`

Comment: @FedericoNafria Just tried adding FooterCntrl in a separate module and including it in myApp module next to ngSanitize and I still have the same problem. Just as I click refresh on home page I can see only {{footerData}} (no data rendered), if I go to ANY other page data is displayed correctly...no error shown in console

Comment: This is really getting more strange, I added the footer data to a link, if I refresh nothing is displayed, if I hover over the link the data is displayed....I am not sure what is this, but if data is displayed upon hover this means at least that the controller is good, just not sure why it is not rendering unless on hover

Comment: just to double check: is it correct that you miss some closing tag?

Comment: @notme no that's just in the question, fixed it now. Index.html is really big so I just copied and pasted sections needed to demonstrate the problem here, and missed a closing tag while copying. Sorry about that

Comment: I think you should provide the whole code. I tried to create [a small plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hu0gN0tO0hQK9EHqfLtX?p=preview) to test your code. It works, but of course since your code is not complete, the error must be something else.